# How to get diff in days include last day of given date in laravel?

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

here is my code for getting diff in days

```
 $endDate = Carbon::parse($input['to_date']);
 $startDate = Carbon::parse($input['from_date']);
 $rentDays = $startDate->diffInDays($endDate);
```

eg. fromdate= '29-11-2021' and to date ='03-12-2021' it returns 4 days. i want to get 5 days

Comment: you could add `1` to it

Comment: it is counting diffrent and you want to include today so you may need to add 1

Comment: ok i will include that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
$rentDays = $startDate->diffInDays($endDate) + 1;
```

or

```
$rentDays = $startDate->diffInDays($endDate->addDays(1));
```